# Generating a Unique ID and appending to Slice

Tags: go

I have a struct:

```
type Records []struct {
    Example string `json:"example"`
    Data    string `json:"data"`
}

type Response struct {
    RecordsCount int `json:"recordsCount"`
    Records      []Records `json:"records"`
}
```

But I want to display this in a collapsing html section, as such:

```
<div class="collapse">
  <input type="checkbox" id="collapse-section1" checked aria-hidden="true">
  <label for="collapse-section1" aria-hidden="true">Collapse section 1</label>
  <div>
    <p>This is the first section of the collapse</p>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="collapse-section2" aria-hidden="true">
  <label for="collapse-section2" aria-hidden="true">Collapse section 2</label>
  <div>
    <p>This is the second section of the collapse</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But in order to do that, i need some kind of ID to replace the actual `id=""` of the `label` and `input`.

But this is the issue, my struct does not have an ID; and sometimes the data is duplicate (i want this to be included), so in order to perform this properly i have to generate an ID, then append it to the slice, and do it that way.

I have no idea how to do that. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Use the slice index as part of the id? Are you using Go templates? If so, you can generate an id using the index.

Comment: Yes i'm using templates. like this, {{range $index, _ := .response}}? @BurakSerdar

Comment: Yes, and then using index like `id="collapse-section{{$index}}"`

Comment: Haha, thank you! Second time you save me. Please submit so i can mark as right answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this using Go templates is to use the array index as part of the id:

```
{{range $index,$item := .response}}
  <input type="checkbox" id="collapse-section{{$index}}" checked aria-hidden="true">
...
```

Comment: this is working fine, however - when i use {{range $index,_ := .response}} it returns an error ( range can only initialize variables ), it works if i remove ,_ but that returns all the data. Any ideas?